# Python Inventory Allocation Optimization using PuLP

Tags: python, optimization, pulp, inventory

I trying to optimize stock allocation using PuLP while maximizing service rate.
material_items is a list of part number.
material_price is a list of prices.
material_demand is a dataframe with material_items as index and quantities per month as columns.

```
from pulp import *

def otif(part_demand, stocks):
    """
    Returns the OnTimeInFull covered with stock using parts demand and stocks
    """  
    df_occ = part_demand[(part_demand !=0)].count(axis=1)
    df_cov =  part_demand[(part_demand !=0) & (part_demand.le(stocks, axis=0))].count(axis = 1)
   
    return df_cov.sum() / df_occ.sum()

# 1. Initiliaze Class
prob = LpProblem("Stock_Optimization", LpMinimize)

# 2. Define Decision Variables
target_otif = 0.89
material_items = list(('a', 'b', 'c'))
material_price = list((10, 1000, 100))
material_demand = pd.DataFrame({'M1': [420, 380, 390],
                                'M2': [50, 40, 45]},
                               index = ['a', 'b', 'c'])

stock_vars = LpVariable.dicts('M', material_items, lowBound=0, cat='Integer')
print('stock_vars')
display(stock_vars)

# 3. Define Objective Function
prob += lpSum([material_price[i]*stock_vars[i] for i in material_items])


# 4. Define Constraints
prob += otif(material_demand,stock_vars) - target_otif == 0

# 5. Solve problem and print result
prob.solve()

print("Status:", LpStatus[prob.status])
for v in prob.variables():
    if v.varValue>0:
        print(v.name, "=", v.varValue)
```

I do not succeed to make this work. I have the following issue:

```
stock_vars

{'a': M_a, 'b': M_b, 'c': M_c}

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-c297b1243bdb> in <module>
     26 
     27 # 3. Define Objective Function
---> 28 prob += lpSum([material_price[i]*stock_vars[i] for i in material_items])
     29 
     30 

<ipython-input-57-c297b1243bdb> in <listcomp>(.0)
     26 
     27 # 3. Define Objective Function
---> 28 prob += lpSum([material_price[i]*stock_vars[i] for i in material_items])
     29 
     30 

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to troubleshoot this well because the problem is not reproducible without data.  However a couple things to help you:

1. Get all of your data squared away (and look at it) before you start the model.  Get out of `pandas` and just put the material, costs, demands, etc. into **dictionaries**.  You have masking, groupby, etc. all going on some something is probably wrong in there, but it is impossible to figure out.  *After* you get the model working using only dictionaries, then maybe tweak it back to work from a dataframe if you like.  Basic idea:  get the simple model working.
2. Your objective statement is not properly constructed.  You have an inequality in there and you are trying to sum over that?  It doesn't make sense.

EDIT:

The first major issue you have is that you are trying to index `material_price` by the items in `material_items`, but you only have it as a list.  It should be:

```
material_price = {  'a': 10,
                    'b': 1000, 
                    'c': 100}
```

I'm not sure what you are doing with the function, but you **cannot** use an arbitrary function as part of a constraint.  You need to construct a *linear expression* out of the variables and parameters in the model, which might be quite complicated for what you appear to be trying to do.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to do it first with dictionaries. For the objective function,  I am trying to count how well inventory covers past demand.  I will comment on this post with the dictionaries

Comment: "how well it covers past demand" sounds like you want to subtract demand.  There should NOT be an inequality in there.  Realize that if `demand[f]` is a fixed number then this will give you the same answer (with different objective value) as just maximizing `stock`.  If you want something more complicated, get the basic model running first and then re-post a succinct question about it.

Comment: Hello, I modified the code to have some basic data.

Comment: see edits above...